# Maven project + JavaFX - cant add weka dependency

Tags: java, maven, javafx, weka

I've been trying to create JavaFX application that uses maven. I've used NetBeans creator for that (Maven -> JavaFX application). Everything worked fine until i decided to add dependency for weka. I'm getting following informations in console:

```
cd C:\Users\Druid\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ProjektWekaWino; "JAVA_HOME=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_74" cmd /c "\"\"D:\\Program files\\NetBeans 8.2\\java\\maven\\bin\\mvn.bat\" -Drunfx.args=\"-jar \\\"${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar\\\" \" -Dmaven.ext.class.path=\"D:\\Program files\\NetBeans 8.2\\java\\maven-nblib\\netbeans-eventspy.jar\" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 clean package org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec\""
Scanning for projects...

------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building ProjektWekaWino 0.1
------------------------------------------------------------------------

--- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ ProjektWekaWino ---
Deleting C:\Users\Druid\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ProjektWekaWino\target

--- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ ProjektWekaWino ---
[debug] execute contextualize
Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
Copying 2 resources

--- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ ProjektWekaWino ---
Changes detected - recompiling the module!
Compiling 2 source files to C:\Users\Druid\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ProjektWekaWino\target\classes

--- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ ProjektWekaWino ---
[debug] execute contextualize
Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\Druid\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ProjektWekaWino\src\test\resources

--- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ ProjektWekaWino ---
Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date

--- maven-surefire-plugin:2.16:test (default-test) @ ProjektWekaWino ---
No tests to run.

--- maven-jar-plugin:2.3.2:jar (default-jar) @ ProjektWekaWino ---
Building jar: C:\Users\Druid\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ProjektWekaWino\target\ProjektWekaWino-0.1.jar

--- maven-dependency-plugin:2.6:unpack-dependencies (unpack-dependencies) @ ProjektWekaWino ---
Unpacking C:\Users\Druid\.m2\repository\com\github\fommil\netlib\netlib-native_system-win-i686\1.1\netlib-native_system-win-i686-1.1-natives.jar to C:\Users\Druid\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ProjektWekaWino\target\classes with includes "" and excludes ""
Unpacking C:\Users\Druid\.m2\repository\nz\ac\waikato\cms\weka\thirdparty\java-cup-11b\2015.03.26\java-cup-11b-2015.03.26.jar to C:\Users\Druid\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ProjektWekaWino\target\classes with includes "" and excludes ""
Unpacking C:\Users\Druid\.m2\repository\com\github\fommil\netlib\core\1.1\core-1.1.jar to C:\Users\Druid\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ProjektWekaWino\target\classes with includes "" and excludes ""
Unpacking C:\Users\Druid\.m2\repository\com\github\fommil\netlib\netlib-native_ref-linux-i686\1.1\netlib-native_ref-linux-i686-1.1-natives.jar to C:\Users\Druid\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ProjektWekaWino\target\classes with includes "" and excludes ""
Unpacking C:\Users\Druid\.m2\repository\com\github\fommil\netlib\netlib-native_ref-linux-armhf\1.1\netlib-native_ref-linux-armhf-1.1-natives.jar to C:\Users\Druid\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ProjektWekaWino\target\classes with includes "" and excludes ""
Unpacking C:\Users\Druid\.m2\repository\com\googlecode\netlib-java\netlib-java\1.1\netlib-java-1.1.jar to C:\Users\Druid\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ProjektWekaWino\target\classes with includes "" and excludes ""
Unpacking C:\Users\Druid\.m2\repository\nz\ac\waikato\cms\weka\weka-stable\3.8.0\weka-stable-3.8.0.jar to C:\Users\Druid\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ProjektWekaWino\target\classes with includes "" and excludes ""
Unpacking C:\Users\Druid\.m2\repository\com\github\fommil\netlib\netlib-native_system-linux-armhf\1.1\netlib-native_system-linux-armhf-1.1-natives.jar to C:\Users\Druid\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ProjektWekaWino\target\classes with includes "" and excludes ""
Unpacking C:\Users\Druid\.m2\repository\com\googlecode\matrix-toolkits-java\mtj\1.0.4\mtj-1.0.4.jar to C:\Users\Druid\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ProjektWekaWino\target\classes with includes "" and excludes ""
Unpacking C:\Users\Druid\.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\f2j\arpack_combined_all\0.1\arpack_combined_all-0.1.jar to C:\Users\Druid\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ProjektWekaWino\target\classes with includes "" and excludes ""
Unpacking C:\Users\Druid\.m2\repository\com\github\fommil\netlib\netlib-native_ref-win-x86_64\1.1\netlib-native_ref-win-x86_64-1.1-natives.jar to C:\Users\Druid\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ProjektWekaWino\target\classes with includes "" and excludes ""
Unpacking C:\Users\Druid\.m2\repository\nz\ac\waikato\cms\weka\thirdparty\java-cup-11b-runtime\2015.03.26\java-cup-11b-runtime-2015.03.26.jar to C:\Users\Druid\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ProjektWekaWino\target\classes with includes "" and excludes ""
Unpacking C:\Users\Druid\.m2\repository\nz\ac\waikato\cms\weka\thirdparty\bounce\0.18\bounce-0.18.jar to C:\Users\Druid\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ProjektWekaWino\target\classes with includes "" and excludes ""
Unpacking C:\Users\Druid\.m2\repository\com\github\fommil\netlib\native_ref-java\1.1\native_ref-java-1.1.jar to C:\Users\Druid\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ProjektWekaWino\target\classes with includes "" and excludes ""
Unpacking C:\Users\Druid\.m2\repository\com\github\fommil\netlib\netlib-native_ref-win-i686\1.1\netlib-native_ref-win-i686-1.1-natives.jar to C:\Users\Druid\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ProjektWekaWino\target\classes with includes "" and excludes ""
Unpacking C:\Users\Druid\.m2\repository\com\github\fommil\netlib\netlib-native_ref-osx-x86_64\1.1\netlib-native_ref-osx-x86_64-1.1-natives.jar to C:\Users\Druid\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ProjektWekaWino\target\classes with includes "" and excludes ""
Unpacking C:\Users\Druid\.m2\repository\com\github\fommil\netlib\native_system-java\1.1\native_system-java-1.1.jar to C:\Users\Druid\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ProjektWekaWino\target\classes with includes "" and excludes ""
Unpacking C:\Users\Druid\.m2\repository\com\github\fommil\netlib\netlib-native_system-win-x86_64\1.1\netlib-native_system-win-x86_64-1.1-natives.jar to C:\Users\Druid\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ProjektWekaWino\target\classes with includes "" and excludes ""
Unpacking C:\Users\Druid\.m2\repository\com\github\fommil\netlib\netlib-native_system-linux-x86_64\1.1\netlib-native_system-linux-x86_64-1.1-natives.jar to C:\Users\Druid\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ProjektWekaWino\target\classes with includes "" and excludes ""
Unpacking C:\Users\Druid\.m2\repository\com\github\fommil\netlib\all\1.1.2\all-1.1.2.pom to C:\Users\Druid\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ProjektWekaWino\target\classes with includes "" and excludes ""
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 47.783s
Finished at: Sat Jun 16 20:55:46 CEST 2018
Final Memory: 22M/215M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.6:unpack-dependencies (unpack-dependencies) on project ProjektWekaWino: Unknown archiver type: No such archiver: 'pom'. -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Below is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.summa</groupId>
    <artifactId>ProjektWekaWino</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>ProjektWekaWino</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <mainClass>com.summa.projektwekawino.MainApp</mainClass>
    </properties>

    <organization>
        <!-- Used as the 'Vendor' for JNLP generation -->
        <name>Your Organisation</name>
    </organization>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludeScope>system</excludeScope>
                            <excludeGroupIds>junit,org.mockito,org.hamcrest</excludeGroupIds>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack-dependencies</id>

                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>${java.home}/../bin/javafxpackager</executable>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>-createjar</argument>
                                <argument>-nocss2bin</argument>
                                <argument>-appclass</argument>
                                <argument>${mainClass}</argument>
                                <argument>-srcdir</argument>
                                <argument>${project.build.directory}/classes</argument>
                                <argument>-outdir</argument>
                                <argument>${project.build.directory}</argument>
                                <argument>-outfile</argument>
                                <argument>${project.build.finalName}.jar</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>                            
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>${java.home}/bin/java</executable>
                            <commandlineArgs>${runfx.args}</commandlineArgs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>  
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <bootclasspath>${sun.boot.class.path}${path.separator}${java.home}/lib/jfxrt.jar</bootclasspath>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.16</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalClasspathElements>
                        <additionalClasspathElement>${java.home}/lib/jfxrt.jar</additionalClasspathElement>
                    </additionalClasspathElements>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka</groupId>
                <artifactId>weka-stable</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
            </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Could anyone tell me what im doing wrong? I've been using weka in my other maven project and it worked pretty fine. Why doesnt it work with JavaFX?

Comment: If there is no special reason to use version 2.6 of the dependency plugin, then you could try it again using the newest version.

Comment: It seems that you used some older tutorial for JavaFX using older JDK7, you wont need `additionalClasspathElement` nor `bootclasspath`, and switch from `1.7` to `1.8`.  Maybe you want to switch to using the javafx-maven-plugin (https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin) Disclaimer: I'm the maintainer of that project!

Comment: @ReneKnop changed that one to 3.1.1, still nothing changed.
FibreFoX - changed JDK to 1.8 and removed those two config elements, still no luck, getting the same error.
I'll try your plugin as soon as i'll be able to and i'll post if it helped.